# How to centre a div in bootstrap 5?

Tags: bootstrap-5

I couldn't find a straightforward way to centre a div in Bootstrap 5. Maybe I am missing something obvious. Google took me to the [flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/) doc.
In Bootstrap 4, I could do it by setting `col-sm-*` and using `col-sm-offset-*`

**Note**: I don't want to centre *the content* in the div. Just need to put whole div in the centre (horizontally). Is setting a margin the only way?

Comment: @cloned Not sure if it applies to bootstrap 5. I just tried adding `justify-content-center` to the div that I want to center but it didn't do it. I also added the `row` class to it. The div just had an mb set: `<div class="mb-8">` I might be missing the obvious

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/flex/#justify-content this is the link for BS5 centering. It's the same as for BS4.

Comment: @cloned looks like it centers the content _within the div_ but not the div itself. The div still spans the page horizontally.

Comment: You have to set a width to the div, otherwise it will span 100% because it's a block element. You should check out hot flexbox works, there is no "magic" way to add a class on a div to center it (and only the div). You can center the div inside a flex-container tough. In the example I linked they centered 3 divs, but it also works with just 1.

Comment: @cloned you are right - thanks. I noticed that `offset` is just a shortcut and that too puts the content in the centre and adds margins. I found out that `offset` can be used in bootstrap5 (class naming has changed) - I'll use that

Answer (score 30):

You can use with `d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center` like below demo:

```css
body{
    height: 100vh;
} 
.container{
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div>
                <h1>You Div</h1>
            </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can also use 'flex-grow-1' class name on container instead of adding height 100% to .container in a stylesheet.